# A better way to getting the latest availaible udp buffer size

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to check the remaining space in UDP buffer, to create alerts beyond a particular percentage. I found one way to parse the file /proc/net/udp. Is there any better way ?

Comment: better than parsing the file /prod/net/udp. It has some information about the udp buffers.The column rx_queue gives information about the packets in the buffer. I was looking if something more straight forward.

Comment: I see, thanks. I dont know of any better way. I just put this here, it may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289830/how-to-monitor-linux-udp-buffer-available-space