# Is it possible to read how many bytes has buffered in a udp socket buffer in Linux c++?

Tags: c++, linux

Is it possible to read how many bytes has buffered in a udp socket buffer in Linux using c++? unfortunately FIONREAD couldn't do that under linux.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2289830/951890

Comment: @Vaughn interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can get the number of bytes available for the current datagram. When you call `recvfrom` pass it the `MSG_PEEK` flag. This will leave the datagram intact but allow you to look at the data and get how many bytes are available.

```
recvfrom(socket, buffer, size, MSG_PEEK, &address, &address_len);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `recv` or `recvfrom` this would be accomplished by setting `flags` to `MSG_PEEK`.

If you are using another method of reading from sockets, let me know and I'll see what I can find.