# How can I get the remaining socket receive buffer size for UDP in java?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, buffer, flow-control

We are developing a reliable-transport-protocol based on UDP. So in order to implement the flow control , we need to know the remaining buffer size. There doesn't seem to be any method in DatagramSocket class which can return the remaining socket buffer size. There is only a "getReceiveBufferSize()" method which returns the total buffer size. Is this not doable or am I looking at wrong place? If that is not doable then how can I implement the flow control feature?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to monitor Linux UDP buffer available space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289830/how-to-monitor-linux-udp-buffer-available-space) possibly holds your answer. At least when you're on linux, windows will be similar. The way I read it it's: "Is this not doable"

Comment: Haha thanks! That make since.